# Count on many-to-many table with the third column on the relationship table

Tags: linq

I have 3 table
Actor(id, name, gender)
Movie(id, name, year)
Casts(aid, mid, role)

I want to print out the actor who has 5 or more distinct role on a film in the year 2005.
So how can i solve this problem using linq?

My first tried: `db.actors.Where(a => a.casts.GroupBy(c => c.movie).Where(c => c.Key.year == 2005).Count() >= 5)`

However, the result is not what i am looking for.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried? also can you show their relationship?

Comment: aid is the foreign key of actor, mid is the foreign key of movie. 
I have tried 
`db.actors.Where(a => a.casts.GroupBy(c => c.movie).Where(c => c.Key.year == 2005).Count() >= 5) `
but it didn't print out as i expected.

Comment: could you add/edit it in your question so we can see clearer

Comment: Question Edited

Comment: so casts has list of actors, list of movies am i correct?

Comment: Yes, you are. it has list of actors and list of movies and the role they play in that movie